# What is the primary key on Person object returned by PlusClass.PeopleApi.GetCurrentPerson?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, google-plus

I am integrating the Google Plus login into my android (Xamarin) application, so want to know what would be the primary key of the person logged in order to get it associated in my Users table.

Thanks.

Comment: The unique identifier of any object returned by any REST request in the G+ API is its ID. You can safely assume that the ID is immutable and unique for each object, including photos, albums and collections. This makes it really easy to store and retrieve objects from a cache or database. The ID for a person generally starts with `1` and is numeric. The ID for an activity (in most cases a post or a reshare) starts with `z` and is alphanumeric. The client libs also provide an `Id` property  (in the C# client) in the data classes.

Comment: Thanks @Evil Talk, this is very useful.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [getCurrentPerson docs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/People#public-methods):

> Returns profile information for the current user. For more information, see: https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get.

Looking at [People.get](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/get#response) you can see that the response is a [person resource](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people#resource-representations) which can include a large amount of data. The important one being `id`.

> id | string | The ID of this person.